# Create an "empty" heading with glowing effect

Tags: html, css, fonts, styling

I am more of a backend developer but got side gig. I have to do a landing page with gloving heading. It should look like this:
[image: Glowing Heading]

I tried to use `-webkit-text-stroke` but it looks odd, something is wrong with some letters:
[image: My Glowing Heading]

Google or chatgpt is no help here. Can somebody maybe have idea how to approach this?

Here are my codepen and figma:
Codepen:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/KramarSenior/pen/GRYoyXb)

Figma:
[Figma](https://www.figma.com/file/TEf2RG2BsaLVk8M4THpsUF/Glowing-Font?node-id=1-46&t=HAwBNEnlLDCVC0wT-0)

I tried to search for help in google and chatgpt but nothing worked.

Comment: Remove the @import statement from your codepen to see a difference.

Comment: @AHaworth You were actually right, the problem came from google fonts. I used font from adobe fonts and looks much better thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code snipppet, if you want to remove the excessive glowing, you can either remove some text-shadows or change the radius or both.

Is this good for you?

```css
body {
  background-color: #2C2B43;
}

h1 {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 144.4%;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2.5996px #9950E2, 0px 0px 6.9141px #9950E2, 0px 0px 11.5332px #9950E2
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Ogarnij porzucone koszyki
</h1>
```

Comment: I mean, it looks slightly better but still, for example, this A letter looks weird inside :/
This gloving "thing", it looks like there is a second text moved 2-3px to the right

Comment: This snippet hasn't done an import of the Montserrat font.

Comment: @AHaworth really? When I inspect the element, in computed values, it shows Monsterrat

Comment: Maybe your system already has it? I was just remarking that the snippet has not done an import of the font which your code in the question has. I find that if I remove that import from the codepen given in the question then the strange 'extra' lines in the characters don't appear - I assume that's because either it's a totally different font or it is the same but rendered differently.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, turned out, there was a problem with google fonts. After importing font from Adobe Font, everything works fine.